# how to flip div on hover using css

Tags: css

i am trying to show backside of card on hover using css. i tried below code but its just roates front div and doesn't display back div. also i want to hide front div on hover. Can anyone fix this problem?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        .content {
            position: relative;
        }
        .front {
            background: darkred;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            transition: 0.5s;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .back {
            background: darkblue;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
        .content:hover .front {
            transform: rotateY(180deg);

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
    <div class="front">Hello</div>
    <div class="back">Bye</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i try to solve you question and this is my answer....

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        .content {
            position: relative;
        }
        .front {
            background: darkred;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            transition: 0.5s;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .back {
            background: darkblue;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
        .content:hover .front {
            transform: rotateY(180deg); 
            opacity: 0;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
    <div class="front">Hello</div>
    <div class="back">Bye</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
.content:hover .front {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

to

```
.content:hover .front {
    display: none
}
```

Check out this 
https://jsfiddle.net/1dsv7e6b/1/

Answer (score 0):

```css
   .content {
        position: relative;
    }
    .front {
        background: darkred;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        transition: 0.5s;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .back {
        background: darkblue;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    .content:hover .front {
        transform: rotateY(180deg); 
        opacity: 0;

    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
    <div class="front">Hello</div>
    <div class="back">Bye</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the same as OP's code

Answer (score 0):

Please add opacity:0;

```
  .content:hover .front {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        opacity:0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [CSS animations](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) here to give the effect of the card flipping but then also being hidden.

The `@keyframes` defines the animation. Here it starts at 0% with no rotation and opacity of 1 (i.e. visible).

Then at 100% the animation is complete at the rotation is 180 degrees and opacity set to 0 so that it is hidden.

```
  @keyframes flip-card {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

You can then apply this on hover like so:

```
.content:hover .front {
  animation: flip-card 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

You use the `animation` property to call the animation and also add how long it should take.

An example can be seen here:
https://jsfiddle.net/368jr1ts/